# Spotfire - Ironpython script to scroll to a specific row in a datatable visualization

Tags: python, datatable, ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I have an Ironpython script that marks one (and only one) row at a time out of thousands rows.

I would like to show the user which row has been marked. The simplest way in my opinion would be to automatically scroll to this row in the visualization.

Is this possible and, if so, how could I achieve this?

Please note that my question is highly related to [this question on tibco community](https://community.tibco.com/questions/it-possible-use-ironpython-script-scroll-particular-row-table-visualization) which was asked 4 years ago by someone else and has no answer yet.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a table visualization. Does the user need to see neighboring rows? If not, you could limit the data in the table to the marking.

Comment: Yes all other rows need to be viewable (even if they are not marked)